# What Is A "Symmetric" Matrix Around A Column or A Midpoint Called?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know the definition of symmetric matrices and ***it is not the right term to be used here*** but is there a known matrix structure like this. If so what it's called?

For example :

When N is odd :

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    a & b & c & m & c & b & a \\
    d & e & f & m & f & e & d \\
    g & h & i & m & i & h & g \\
    k & l & n & m & n & l & k \\
    o & p & q & m & q & p & o \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

When N is even:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    a & b & c & c & b & a \\
    d & e & f & f & e & d \\
    g & h & i &i & h & g \\
    k & l & n &n & l & k \\
    o & p & q & q & p & o \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Basically, it's mirrored around a column / row or midpoint. Also, other than the vertex ( column / row or midpoint ), numbers could be repeated or different.

Comment: Hello Ahmed, welcome to MSE. Can you please type the matrices in your question instead of including links? [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is explained how to type math using MathJax.

Comment: Thanks @Ernie060 that was helpful.

Comment: This is almost the condition that $AB = A$, where $B$ is the matrix with 1's along the antidiagonal, and 0's elsewhere.